# PyTorch runs as expected under Windows, but fails on larger images under Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, pytorch

I've trained a `segmentation_models_pytorch.PSPNet` model for image segmentation. For prediction I load whole image in `PyTorch tensor` and scan it with 384x384 pixels window.

```
result = model.predict(image_tensor[:, :, y:y+384, x:x+384])
```

My Windows machine has 6Gb GPU, while Ubuntu has 8 Gb GPU. When all models are loaded they consume some 1.4 Gb GPU. When processing a large image on Windows the memory consumption increases to 1.7 Gb GPU.

Under Windows the model can handle 25 M pixel images. Under Ubuntu the same code can only process up to 5 M pixel image. Debugging is difficult because I only have ssh access to the Ubuntu machine.
What could cause this discrepancy and how to debug this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check cuda version, torch version.

To debug, you can just print image_tensor.shape before model.predict, maybe you are running a larger batch size on linux machine.

Comment: You could consider recreating an up to date env with conda which is good to determine all the versions of all the required dependencies and other required executables

Answer (score 1):

## First approach to solve:

I should first check the libraries version of the CUDA, Pytorch, and other python libraries in general. If they are all equal, then check for compatibility of libraries in Ubunto and your GPU drive/CUDA.

As commented by Jimmy, you can use a conda environment or a virtual environment directly on Python `python3 -m venv env` to control the libraries' version.

## To debug

You can install a Python IDE that allows you to debug. If not possible, one very simple but inefficient approach is to print on many parts of your code to see what exactly is different from your execution on Windows.